# Standalone compilation of sources intended for \input{} or \include{}

Tags: include

My LaTeX workflow involves frequent recompiles (good ol' C-c C-c in AucTeX).  Right now I'm working on a large document that's composed of chapters, each in an individual file.  I would like to use the `\input{}` or `\include{}` mechanism to compile the final document, however that involves stripping the chapters sources from the preamble.

I could create a "main" file (a chapter-main.tex for every chapter.tex) with the preamble and `\include{chapter.tex}`, but this means that as I'm editing an individual chapter, I need to switch to a different file for a recompilation, which breaks my workflow.

Are there any ways to use the `\include{}` mechanism that don't get in the way of editing files individually?..

Comment: In TeXShop you can set a "project root" embedded in a comment at the top of a file.  That way when you use the keycombination for compiling, what's compiles is not the currently edited file but the root file.  Is that a feature of AucTeX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using the following solution: `\usepackage{standalone}` combined with `\usepackage{import}`.  This is probably not the most general solution, but was easiest to implement for my purposes.

The standalone package ignores the preambles for individual files, so any `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand` statements need to go inside `\begin{document}`, and all the packages individual files use need to be declared in the "master" file's preamble.  Those were the only changes I needed to make to my chapter files; after that I simply include them into the master file using the import package (this helps takes care of handling relative paths):

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\import{chapters/introduction/}{introduction}
```

etc.

Answer (score 3):

[There are several solutions for working with multiple files](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-multidoc); I prefer `subfiles`. If you merely want to indicate which file is the "master", insert the following at the top of the file (and replace "rootfile" as appropriate):

```
% Local Variables: 
% TeX-master: "rootfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

TeXnicCenter allows for compiling the "current" document (the file being edited) through a single "build file" button. Additionally, a "build project" button will compile the "master" file. This allows for editing and compiling of (say) chapters without having to switch back to the "master" document for a recompile. Hope this helps, W